# Get keys and values from Json file using GitLab-ci

Tags: json, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm creating a gitlab-ci.yml file where I need to iterate in a json file and extract the keys and values. I cannot use jq and I am trying with a cat command to do this. This is my script:

```
script:
          while read line
          do
            echo $line
          done < $myfile
```

And this is myfile:

```
{"var1":"test1",
"other_var":"test2"}
```

Since I am not able to use jq becuase is not installed and my customer doesn't allow me to install it, how I can make a print like this one:

```
"Key is var1 and value is test1"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551193/how-to-find-value-of-key-value-in-json-in-bash-script) provides some options for you, including [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694241) using `grep` (based on [this blog post](https://brianchildress.co/parse-json-using-grep)), [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551229) using `cat` and `awk`, and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729048) using `pcregrep` or `sed`.